# Defining predicates in prolog , work with lists

Tags: prolog, logic, predicate

Using prolog,

Define the predicate, frequentest(InList, OutList), where OutList is a list of all elements that occur most often in list InList.

Using the above predicate, define a list
"OutList" of all elements that occur most often in the given list "InList".

Comment: Do you have examples of inputs and expected results?

Comment: For example, I enter the list InList [1,4,8,4,5,4,8,4,7,8] and the list OutList looks like: [4,8]

Comment: 4 appears more times than 8 in [1,4,8,4,5,4,8,4,7,8], so why wouldn't the output be `[4]`? Your definition of "most often" should be made clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is code for a reasonable interpretation of "most often":

```
frequentest(LstElems, FrequentestElems) :-
    % Sort, keeping any duplicates
    msort(LstElems, Sorted),
    frequentest_(Sorted, _E, 0, 0, [], FrequentestElems).

frequentest_([], Elem, Count, Max, LstMax, F) :-
    frequentest_upd_(Count, Elem, Max, LstMax, _Max1, F).
frequentest_([Elem|Sorted], Elem, Count, Max, LstMax, F) :-
    !,
    Count1 is Count + 1,
    frequentest_(Sorted, Elem, Count1, Max, LstMax, F).
frequentest_([H|Sorted], Elem, Count, Max, LstMax, F) :-
    frequentest_upd_(Count, Elem, Max, LstMax, Max1, LstMax1),
    frequentest_(Sorted, H, 1, Max1, LstMax1, F).
    
frequentest_upd_(0, _E, _M, _L, _M1, _LM1) :- !.
frequentest_upd_(Count, Elem, Max, LstMax, Max1, LstMax1) :-
    compare(Comp, Count, Max),
    frequentest_upd_comp_(Comp, Count, Elem, Max, LstMax, Max1, LstMax1).

frequentest_upd_comp_(<, _Count, _Elem, Max, LstMax, Max, LstMax).
frequentest_upd_comp_(=, _Count, Elem, Max, LstMax, Max, [Elem|LstMax]).
frequentest_upd_comp_(>, Count, Elem, _Max, _LstMax, Count, [Elem]).
```

Results in swi-prolog:

```
?- time(frequentest([a,b,c,a], F)).
% 16 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (88% CPU, 516829 Lips)
F = [a].

?- time(frequentest([a,b,c,a,b], F)).
% 17 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (85% CPU, 1247615 Lips)
F = [b, a].

?- time(frequentest([a,b,c], F)).
% 15 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (82% CPU, 816327 Lips)
F = [c, b, a].

?- time(frequentest([1,4,8,4,5,4,8,4,7,8], F)).
% 28 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (91% CPU, 779575 Lips)
F = [4].
```